# Why will MySQL not run on xampp?

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I tried to run MySQL on Xampp it says this:

> Attempting to start MySQL app...
>
> Status change detected: running
>
> Status change detected: stopped
>
> Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
>   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>
> Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> If you need more help, copy and post this
>   entire log window on the forums

I have been looking for an answer for about an hour and nothing has worked. If anybody knows a possible  solution please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Did you do what it suggested, i.e. check the Windows Event Viewer for error messages?  What did you find?  Have you eliminated the causes that are _listed right there in the message_?  Which ones?

Answer (score -1):

Try to run xammp in the Administrator mode.

Comment: How will i do that? Sorry if im asking a ton of questions, im new with xampp.....

Comment: If you are using the Linux try to run in superuser mode, if you are running it on windows right click the xammp icon , there is an option of Run in administrator mode, (if you are not already)!!